# Change elevations of a Slab or Rectangle using python in blender

Tags: python

How do you create a slab (30x40x1) with different elevations every 5'? I am not a programmer nor do I know python. I managed to write the following but I know there has to be a better simpler way to write this.

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Slab",
    "author": "A O, P.E.",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 90, 1),
    "location": "View3D > Object",
    "description": "Adds a Slab Mesh Object",
    "warning": "",
    "doc_url": "",
    "category": "Object",
}


import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy.props import FloatVectorProperty
#from bpy_extras.object_utils import AddObjectHelper, object_data_add
from mathutils import Vector
from bpy.types import (
    AddonPreferences,
    Operator,
    Panel,
    PropertyGroup,
)
from bpy.props import (IntProperty)

class OBJECT_OT_cube(Operator):
    bl_label = "Slab"
    bl_idname = "object.cube"
    #bl_description = "Adds a Slab Mesh Object"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    #bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
    bl_catagory = "Slab"
    
    cubeResolution: bpy.props.IntProperty(
        name = "Cube Resolution",
        default = 6,
        min = 1,
        max = 15,
    description = "Octree Depth used in the Remesh Modifier",
)

   
    scale: FloatVectorProperty(
        name="scale",
        default=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
        subtype='TRANSLATION',
        description="scaling",
    )

        #def poll(cls, context):
        #return context.object.select_get() and context.object.type == 'CUBE' or     context.object.type == 'CURVE'

        #def invoke(self, context, event):
        #return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self)
    

#Distances are in 5 meters. Change distances as per your project
#Define verices,faces,edges

verts = [
(0,0,10),(0,5,10),(5,5,10),(5,0,10),(0,0,10.41),(0,5,10.33),(5,5,10.31),(5,0,10.4),(0,10,10),(5,10,10),(0,10,10.15),(5,10,10.15),(10,0,10),(10,5,10),(10,5,10.3),(10,0,10.39),
(15,0,10),(15,5,10),(15,5,10.26),(15,0,10.37),
(20,0,10),(20,5,10),(20,5,10.28),(20,0,10.39),
(0,15,10),(5,15,10),(0,15,10.06),(5,15,10.04),
(10,10,10),(10,10,10.115),(10,15,10),(10,15,10.085),
(15,10,10),(15,10,10.13),(15,15,10),(15,15,10.13),
(20,10,10),(20,10,10.17),(20,15,10),(20,15,10.18),
(0,20,10),(5,20,10),(0,20,10.01),(5,20,9.97),
(10,20,10),(10,20,9.99),(15,20,10),(15,20,10.02),
(20,20,10),(20,20,10.11),(25,0,10),(25,5,10),(25,0,10.39),(25,5,10.31),
(25,10,10),(25,10,10.21),(25,15,10),(25,15,10.21),(25,20,10),(25,20,10.13),
(0,25,10),(0,25,9.97),(5,25,10),(5,25,9.97),(10,25,10),(10,25,9.96),
(20,25,10),(20,25,10.04),(25,25,10),(25,25,10.055),
(15,25,10),(15,25,9.99)]

faces = [
(0,1,2,3),(7,6,5,4),(0,4,5,1),(1,5,6,2),(2,6,7,3),(3,7,4,0),
(1,8,9,2),(5,10,11,6),(2,6,11,9),(1,5,10,8),(8,9,11,10),
(7,15,12,3),(15,14,13,12),(6,14,13,2),(7,15,14,6),(3,12,13,2),
(12,16,17,13),(16,19,18,17),(13,17,18,14),(12,16,19,15),(15,19,18,14),
(16,17,21,20),(19,18,22,23),(23,22,21,20),(17,18,22,21),(16,19,23,20),(8,9,25,24),(11,10,26,27),(25,27,26,24),(9,11,27,25),(8,10,26,24),
(21,36,32,17),(22,37,33,18),(21,22,37,36),(17,18,33,32),(32,33,37,36),(18,14,29,33),(17,13,28,32),(13,14,29,28),(32,33,29,28),(28,29,11,9),(28,13,2,9),(29,14,6,11),(9,25,30,28),(29,11,27,31),(25,27,31,30),(28,29,31,30),(32,28,30,34),(30,31,35,34),(34,35,39,38),(36,32,34,38),
(32,33,35,34),(36,37,39,38),(37,33,35,39),(33,29,31,35),
(24,40,41,25),(25,41,44,30),(30,44,46,34),(34,46,48,38),
(24,26,42,40),(25,27,43,41),(31,45,44,30),(34,35,47,46),(38,39,49,48),
(27,26,42,43),(27,43,45,31),(35,31,45,47),(39,35,47,49),
(40,41,43,42),(41,44,45,43),(44,46,47,45),(47,46,48,49),(46,70,64,44),
(20,21,51,50),(20,23,52,50),(50,52,53,51),(21,22,53,51),(23,22,53,52),
(48,49,67,66),(58,48,66,68),(58,59,49,48),(69,67,66,68),(59,49,67,69),(59,69,68,58),(40,42,61,60),(41,43,63,62),(44,45,65,64),
(42,61,63,43),(40,60,62,41),(61,60,62,63),
(44,41,62,64),(45,43,63,65),(70,46,47,71),(47,45,65,71),(71,65,64,70),
(66,48,46,70),(49,47,71,67),
(36,37,55,54),(36,21,51,54),(38,39,57,56),(36,54,56,38),
(38,48,58,56),
(22,37,55,53),(51,53,55,54),(55,37,39,57),(54,55,57,56),
(39,49,59,57),(56,57,59,58),(67,71,70,66),(65,63,62,64)]


#Define mesh and object
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("Cube")
object = bpy.data.objects.new("Cube",mesh)

#Set location and scene of object
object.location = bpy.context.scene.cursor.location
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(object)

#Create mesh
mesh.from_pydata(verts,[],faces)
mesh.update(calc_edges=True)



def execute(self, context):

        add_object(self, context)
      
        return {'FINISHED'}

def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(OBJECT_OT_cube.bl_idname)


# Registration

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_OT_cube)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.append(menu_func)
 
  
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_OT_cube)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.remove(menu_func)
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [bmesh.ops.duplicate](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.ops.html#bmesh.ops.duplicate) and [bmesh.ops.translate](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.ops.html#bmesh.ops.translate).

```
import bpy
import bmesh

slab_dimensions = (30, 40, 1)
storeys = 10
storey_height = 5

mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("Slab")
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(mesh)
bmesh.ops.create_cube(bm, size=1)
bmesh.ops.scale(bm, vec=slab_dimensions, verts=bm.verts)
bmesh.ops.translate(bm, vec=(0.0, 0.0, slab_dimensions[2] / 2), verts=bm.verts)
slab_faces = bm.faces[:]

for i in range(storeys):
    dupe = bmesh.ops.duplicate(bm, geom=slab_faces)
    verts = [v for v in dupe["geom"] if isinstance(v, bmesh.types.BMVert)]
    bmesh.ops.translate(bm, vec=(0.0, 0.0, storey_height * i), verts=verts)

bm.to_mesh(mesh)

obj = bpy.data.objects.new("Slab", mesh)
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(obj)
```

Result :

[image]